# How to have a running total in Excel

Tags: excel, cumulative-sum

How do I get a running total for a row I will only have partial data for?

[image: Running Total Table]

In `Column I` of my example (*Running Total Comparison*), I would like to compare the sum of the cells I have information for in *Sales Week 2* (`B3:D3`) with those same cells from *Sales Week 1* (`B2:D2`). If I add data to `E3`, I would then need to compare the sums for (`B3:E3`) and (`B2:E2`).

Answer (score 1):

For Sales Week 1,

```
=sum(b2:index(2:2, match(1e99, 3:3)))
```

For Sales Week 2,

```
=sum(b3:index(3:3, match(1e99, 3:3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this formula in cell `I2`, then drag it to the bottom...

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B2,0,0,1,LOOKUP(2,1/($B$3:$H$3<>""),COLUMN($B$3:$H$3))-1))
```

[image]

Comment: It could be `COUNT` instead of `COUNTA` but there is a potential problem if a week day in a sales week row is blank (e.g. sun, mon, tue, thu have values but wed is blank)

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, formula adjusted to include blanks.

Comment: Thank you guys! This was very helpful.

Comment: @MeganPeters, please accept one of the answers so future visitors know what ended up working for you. Thanks.